# Java library for wiki format strings? [b] to <strong>, [url] to <a href>

Tags: java, string, format, wiki

I need a lightweight, easy and customizable (i can control which tags to be enabled/disabled) library to identify and replace "wiki-ish" markup language to HTML in Strings.

For example:

```
[b]hello[/b] would be <strong>hello</strong>

[url]hello[/url] would be <a href="hello">hello</a>
```

Comment: As far as I can see, you mean BBCode: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bbcode

Comment: Yupp, and Googleing that and Java gave me answers. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As MvanGeest mentioned, that specific markup looks like BBCode, in which case you can try something like [kefir-bb](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kefir-bb/)